PyTorch DeiT model keeps predicting one class no matter what
We are trying to fine-tune a custom model on an imported DeiT distilled patch16 384 pretrained model.
Output:
Cost at epoch 0 is 4.611058227040551
Cost at epoch 1 is 0.9889081553979353
test set accuracy
Checking accuracy
scores: tensor([[ 33.9686,  33.2787, -31.1509,  ..., -25.5279, -36.7728, -24.9331],
        [ 33.9695,  33.2792, -31.1509,  ..., -25.5264, -36.7719, -24.9356],
        [ 33.9690,  33.2784, -31.1496,  ..., -25.5270, -36.7717, -24.9326],
        ...,
        [ 33.9692,  33.2780, -31.1487,  ..., -25.5267, -36.7713, -24.9314],
        [ 33.9654,  33.2793, -31.1575,  ..., -25.5372, -36.7818, -24.9307],
        [ 33.9687,  33.2778, -31.1490,  ..., -25.5278, -36.7719, -24.9300]],
       device='cuda:0')
predictions: tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
y: tensor([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], device='cuda:0') 

###  many more prints later
predictions: tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
y: tensor([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], device='cuda:0')
Got 80 / 198 with accuracy 40.40
Precision: 0.1632
Recall: 0.4040
F1-Score: 0.2325

The folder is structured as KneeOsteoarthritisXray with subfolders train, test, and val (ignoring val because we just want it to work) and each of those have subfolders 0 and 1 (0 is healthy, 1 has osteoarthritis)
The model predicts only 0's and returns an accuracy equal to the amount of 0's in the dataset
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
#import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision
from transformers import DeiTForImageClassificationWithTeacher, DeiTImageProcessor

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

class myDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.data = []

        for label in os.listdir(root_dir):
            label_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, label)
            if os.path.isdir(label_dir):
                for file in os.listdir(label_dir):
                    self.data.append((os.path.join(label_dir, file), int(label)))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path, label = self.data[idx]
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        #print(f'image before normalization: {image}') #DEBUG
        image = transform(image)
        #print(f'image after normalization to 0-1{image}') #DEBUG
        image_np = np.array(image) 
        return image, label

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 32

model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/PyTorchdeit-base-distilled-patch16-384/"
model = DeiTForImageClassificationWithTeacher.from_pretrained(model_path)
model.to(device)

train_dataset = myDataset(root_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/KneeOsteoarthritisXray/train")
#val_dataset = myDataset(root_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/KneeOsteoarthritisXray/val")
test_dataset = myDataset(root_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/KneeOsteoarthritisXray/test")

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
#val_loader = DataLoader(dataset=val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    losses = []

    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = data.to(device=device)
        targets = targets.to(device=device)

        scores = model(data)['logits']
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

    print(f'Cost at epoch {epoch} is {(sum(losses)/len(losses))}')
  

def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    print("Checking accuracy")
    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0
    all_labels = []
    all_preds = []

    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
      for x, y in loader:
          x = x.to(device=device)
          y = y.to(device=device)

          scores = model(x)['logits']
          print(f'scores: {scores}')
          _, predictions = scores.max(1)
          print(f'predictions: {predictions}')
          print(f'y: {y}')

          all_labels.extend(y.cpu().numpy())
          all_preds.extend(predictions.cpu().numpy())

          num_correct += (predictions == y).sum() #.item()
          num_samples += predictions.size(0)

    print(f'Got {num_correct} / {num_samples} with accuracy {float(num_correct)/float(num_samples)*100:.2f}')

    precision = precision_score(all_labels, all_preds, average='weighted')
    recall = recall_score(all_labels, all_preds, average='weighted')
    f1 = f1_score(all_labels, all_preds, average='weighted')

    print(f'Precision: {precision:.4f}')
    print(f'Recall: {recall:.4f}')
    print(f'F1-Score: {f1:.4f}')

    model.train()

print('test set accuracy')
check_accuracy(test_loader, model)

We don't think it's overfitting because we tried with unbalanced and balanced versions of the dataset, we tried overfitting a small dataset, and many other attempts.
We checked out many many similar complaints and can't really get anything out of their code or solutions

As you said you are using DeiT model and the learning rate for training the model like Deit is relatively high which leads model to converge to a sub optimal solution and that is why your model is favouring only one class.You try to reduce the learning rate(for ex:1-e4)and check now it may give you altogether solution.
